# Is it good practice to use one UIViewController for both adding and updating records?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller

I'm developing an app for iPad. I have a form (UIViewController) for adding new records (of type Person) to my sqlite3 database.

For updating (i.e. modifying) records, I was considering using the same UIViewController, but I want to know what's better: one UIViewController for adding and another for updating, or one UIViewController for both adding and updating?

Comment: There isn't quite enough detail here for us to be able to help you; what kind of record are you using? Are you using core data? What do adding and updating mean? Normally you wouldn't use a view controller for data management.

Comment: In many cases, I use one VC for both new and existing records (of any kind). I use a `BOOL` in my "editing" VC to indicate if I'm in “creation" or "editing" mode. But I do use two separate VCs if the process of creating and changing records differs greatly. Examples: the Contacts app uses one VC (I suppose), for both creating and editing contacts.

Comment: I'm using CoreData. Adding mean Person *person = NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Person" inManagedObjectContext:context]. So if ViewController is not for data management, what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the amount of overlap.

If updating a record presents all the same information as creating a record, then it will be less lines of code, and less duplication, thus easier to maintain if there is one view controller.

You could even have two different storyboard views using the same view controller. This will let you give a different look when creating or updating records. I think it's good to have a noticeable visual differences for different operations. It gives a visual clue to the user as to what operation they are currently performing.

On the other hand, if there are different business rules when updating records, or if there is a different workflow when creating a new record, then two view controllers may prevent lots of branching code reducing the cognitive complexity.

In this case, you may want to consider subclassing one view controller from the other.

Comment: +1, but I'd say that subclassing is usually not a good approach in these cases. Having a delegate for your view controller, including configurable properties or just having separate xibs are almost always preferable to subclassing.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a little vague. Let me check my understanding:

- You're writing code in Obj-C that involves a type called `Person` that has some information
- You have a form by which a human fills out the information in type `Person`.
- You then helpfully give that human an "updating" notice of some sort, so they know you're working hard, not hardly working.

Your question is whether you should use one `UIViewController` for the form and one for the updating notice, or use one that covers both cases, correct?

If that's your question, I'd answer that it's largely a matter of taste, but you probably don't need a whole new `UIViewController` for the update notice. I'm not even convinced you need a different view, never mind its controller. You *can* do it either way as you prefer, but I'd recommend the simplest option that does what you need.